# Is there an alternate $\chi^2$ calculation useful for data spanning a large scale?

Tags: chi-squared-test, chemometrics

I have experimental small angle scattering data which provide information about the structure of a molecule.  I can use a PDB file of a molecular structure (contains all the atom names and coordinates) to calculate what the equivalent scattering would be for the structure in that PDB file.  I am generating different structure files, calculating the scattering from them, then comparing that calculated data to the experimental data to evaluate how closely they match.  I have been using the reduced $\chi^2$ statistic to rank the goodness of fit between each model result and the experimental data,

$$
\chi^2=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\left(y_{exp}(x_i)-y_{mod}(x_i)\right)^2}{(\partial y_{exp}(x_i))^2}
,$$

where $y_{exp}$ is the experimental data, $y_{mod}$ is the model data, and $N$ is the number of $x$ data points.

The nature of the data is such that important features span a large scale in $y$, i.e. even though the calculated difference at high x value is small compared to low x values, it is the difference on a log plot which matters.  For this reason, we typically view the data on a log scale as shown in the example comparison.  Additionally, we can freely scale either the experimental or model data by multiplying all the $y$ values by a constant, creating an offset on the log plot (hence the $[\text{arbitrary units}]$ label for the $y$-axis).  More important than the match of any one point is that the overall shape of the two curves match, i.e. it is much better that all points deviate by a small amount rather than a few points deviating by a large amount (unfortunately, the $\chi^2$ statistic does not differentiate these two cases).

Below the plot I show a histogram of the contribution to the $\chi^2$ sum from each $x$ value.  Despite the much better match on the left (shape wise), this is still where the majority of $\chi^2$ is coming from. The dip close to the middle and the differences on the right only contribute about 30%.  Part of this is because the error is smaller for lower $x$ compared to higher $x$ but I think the real problem is the that $y$ changes by several orders of magnitude as $x$ increases.

The data over the entire range of $x$ is equally significant but inherent in how $\chi^2$ is defined, the higher signal data at low $x$ values gets fit with more priority.  **Is there a more appropriate measure of discrepancy to compare the model data to the experimental data which will prioritize the shape when plotted on a log scale?**

[image]

I have discussed this with other experienced scientist who do these type of measurements and the consensus is that the $\chi^2$ comparison has significant limitations but we are not sure a better tool to use.  I have seen some publications which get around this by only calculating the $\chi^2$ of a narrow $x$-range.  For a more complete solution, it seems like some kind of scaling should produce the desired results but I am not sure the statistics behind that.  I was hoping experienced statistics people could provide helpful insight.

Comment: I've edited your post to use mathjax formatting. Please check that it still says what you intend. A tutorial can be found here. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user777,  It's good to know I can directly use $\LaTeX$ formating on StackExchange (saves me making latex figures).  Thanks!

Comment: `Despite the much better match on the left,...` Since this plot is on a log scale, I'm not certain that this is true. How do things look on a regular plot?

Comment: @EricFarng, I was trying to make the point that I am interested in the fit of the data as normalized using the $log(y)$.  I tried using $log(y(x_i))$ instead of $y(x_i)$ in the $\sum$ but it was not clear the most reasonable way to convert the error.  I tried scaling the error using $$\frac{\log_{10}(y(x_i) + \partial y(x_i)) - log_{10}(y(x_i) - \partial y(x_i))}{2}$$ I get a similar result and I am not sure the validity of the error scaling.

Comment: Not all SE, unfortunately. AFAIK, only CV.SE and Math.SE have mathjax; notably, SO.SE does not.

Comment: You lost me at the very beginning. One doesn't use a $\chi^2$ test to fit a model--one uses it to check goodness of fit.  You might be going down a fruitless path.  This suggests that you consider editing this post to tell us more about the original problem that led you to this approach: it will enable readers to supply useful suggestions.

Comment: @whuber, I added more details.  I can explain more if needed.

Comment: Thank you. My misunderstanding stemmed from your use of the word "test". You do not appear to be conducting a $\chi^2$ test at all: you are merely choosing to use a $\chi^2$ *statistic* as a measure of discrepancy between a library distribution and an observed distribution. If this interpretation is right, then your question really ought to be "how can I choose an appropriate measure of distributional discrepancy to match my physical understanding and decision needs in this problem?" That suggests you should explain as much as possible about those requirements.

Comment: @whuber, I am not certain what you mean by "library distribution" and "observed distribution".  I use the $\chi^2$ to _rank_ each calculated curve according to its discrepancy.  I tried to implement you comment and provide the added information of the requirements (though I fear it is becoming a wall of text).

Comment: Those are terms from quantitative spectroscopy: the "library" distribution is what you derive from your file and the "observed" distribution is what you see in your molecule.  The whole point of my comments is that your question appears to ask how to perform the ranking in a way that is meaningful for your analytical objectives and/or has a physical meaning. Although we can provide some statistical guidance, the solution shouldn't be entirely a statistical one: ultimately it *must* be informed by this domain knowledge and context.

Comment: @whuber, The "domain knowledge" is that it should prioritize many small differences as a better match than a few large differences (even if the sum of the squared difference is the same).  Also to somehow normalize the data so the orders of magnitude variation in scale is not a significant factor.